# Sharing an object between activities

Tags: android

I have a Weather app with four Activities. The main/launcher activity is 'invisible' using...

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

...and is simply used to do a few checks (whether this is a new install, whether a network connection is available etc) before firing off one of the other Activities. The other Activities are UI-oriented - two simply display weather data pulled from a website and the third to provide a location 'picker' so the user can choose which area to show the weather for.

However, all four activities make use of a WeatherHelper object which basically does everything from checking for available SD card storage to maintaining preferences and pulling/formatting website pages.

So, my question(s)...what is the best way to have one instance of WeatherHelper which can be used by multiple activities and where/how are best to create it in my case?

I've been an OO programmer for a lot of years but I'm very new to Android and the design concepts - I've read a lot on the Android Developers site over the past weeks but I've stalled trying to decide on this.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would store shared information in you [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object. Subclass this and add any extra initialization and data there. You can get your application using [getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29) from your activity, which you can cast to your specialized version and access the shared data.

I would also avoid launching the special startup activity if possible and do the work in your Application's onCreate() override.

Comment: Thank you! A case of not being able to 'see the wood for the trees' - I was concentrating so much on the activities, I didn't see the bigger picture. I agree about avoiding the startup activity (I don't like doing it that way) - the Application's onCreate() override may well prove a better approach.

Comment: Another perfectly acceptable solution is to use a Singleton, which can be lazily initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question has been answered, but it seems like it would be much simpler to instantiate your `WeatherHelper` object in the `onCreate()` of the `Activity` that has the launcher intent, and make the `WeatherHelper` static.

Comment: I thought they were alive during the lifetime of the entire application. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Snailer - it was one option that I had been considering but I'm new to Java from a C++ and C# background where 'static' has (some) different implications - I'll leave experimenting until a later date.

Comment: No problem. I'm new to Java as well, just trying to help!