# android BlutoothChatService use in multiple classes

Tags: android, bluetooth

im using the BluetoothChat sample in order to establish a bluetooth communication. Ive created SecondView.java now and i want to send and receive data from there without having to reconnect to the bluetooth. Is there any way to access the send and receive methods used in the BluetoothChat.java example to my SecondView.java?I found that a working method is to use Bound Service but i dont know how to implement this..

Comment: Instead of trying to use send and receive in BluetoothChat.java from SecondView.java, how about just modifying BluetoothChat.java to have the functionality you created in SecondView, so your resulting class has all the functionality you need?  Do you need both classes?

Comment: No, for the purpose of my application i must be able to send and receive data from multiple classes

Comment: Here are a couple of options that may work.  One is to create the BluetoothChatService object ("mChatService" in the example) in your Application object, instead of in the BluetoothChat class, as referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272906/sharing-an-object-between-activities.  This way you have all of the methods and data from BluetoothChatService available to you in all of your classes.  Another option is to use Fragments (see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).  This would allow the sharing of not just functionality, but also UI elements.

Comment: For future references. Original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790419/android-bluetoothchat-use-send-receive-methods-from-another-class

Answer (score 3):

If you are following the bluetooth chat example, then you will be using threads for bluetooth communication, e.g. a connectedthread that has the read and write methods for bluetooth communication.

Its actually really simple to be able to read and write from anywhere in your app. You just need to have a global reference to that thread for your application.

In a android app, the application has a context that is a global across your entire app. You can get this with the getApplication() method from any activity. To set your own variables on the 'Application' context, you need to extend the application class, and point your manifest towards it.

Heres an example. I've extended the application class, and made a variable for the connected thread, with getter and setter methods.

```
class MyAppApplication extends Application {
        private ConnectedThread mBluetoothConnectedThread;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }

        public ConnectedThread getBluetoothConnectedThread() {
            return mBluetoothConnectedThread;
        }

        public void setBluetoothConnectedThread(ConnectedThread mBluetoothConnectedThread) {
            this.mBluetoothConnectedThread = mBluetoothConnectedThread;
        }

    }
```

And to point your manifest towards that class, you need to set the android:name attribute of the application element to the class name of the application class we created above. E.g.

```
 <application
        android:name="com.myapp.package.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Once thats done you can access the ConnectedThread at any in a activity by calling

```
MyAppApplication.getBluetoothConnectedThread().write()
MyAppApplication.getBluetoothConnectedThread().read()
```

Note that you need to set the thread to the model first once its created:

```
MyAppApplication.setBluetoothConnectedThread(MyNewConnectedThread);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello! thanx for your answer, i have some questions. Im using the bluetooth chat example and BleutoothChatService class has the read and write methods, so i changed the "private ConnectedThread mBluetoothConnectedThread;" to "private BluetoothChatService mBluetoothConnectedThread;" .Is this the right way?
Also in the activity that i want to access the "ConnectedThread", the class will "extends Activity" or something else?
And finally where exactly do i call this one "MyAppApplication.setBluetoothConnectedThread(MyNewConnectedThread);"?
thanx again

Comment: Yes if you are using the BluetoothChatService you need to add a private BluetoothChatService mBluetoothChatService; to your application class (also make sure you create the class etc like is done in the BluetoothChat activity. You are basically taking all the bluetooth chat stuff out of the BluetoothChat activity and moving it to the Application class.
You can call MyAppApplication.setBluetoothConnectedThread(MyNewConnectedThread) from any class in your application, because it's just calling a class and the Application class will only ever have one instance in the lifetime of your application.