# Android: BluetoothChat example with multiple activities

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to edit the Android **BluetoothChat** example to be able to use it with **multiple activities**. Therefor I created a class that *extends Application* as adviced over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12911678)

```
public class cBaseApplication extends Application {

    public static cBaseApplication context;

    private BluetoothChatService mBluetoothConnectedThread;

    // Local Bluetooth adapter
    private static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        context = this;

        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    public BluetoothChatService getBluetoothConnectedThread() {
        return mBluetoothConnectedThread;
    }

    public void setBluetoothConnectedThread(BluetoothChatService mBluetoothConnectedThread) {
        this.mBluetoothConnectedThread = mBluetoothConnectedThread;
    }

    public static BluetoothAdapter getBluetoothAdapter() {
        return mBluetoothAdapter;
    }

}
```

**What I am having trouble with is:** Moving the needed code from the original BluetoothChat class to the new application class.

i.e.

```
// Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
        mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(this, mHandler);
```